# wx.ToolTip not displaying message

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Not sure why this section of code refuses to show the tool tip on either a TextCtrl or a simple button. All the examples I've read indicates that it should work. No errors are generated and it compiles fine. The tool tip is meant to be shown when the user places the mouse over the TextCtrl as to indicate how the text should be entered.

Is it possible because I am on a Mac running the latest OS that the code isn't compatible? I don't have a Windows box here to test it but everything I've read online indicates that this is valid code and should work. Also, because the text and buttons are in a horizontal box sizer, would this have anything to do with the code not being shown?

Thanks!

```
    # Item Sizer
    self.txtItem = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Item: ")
    self.inpItem = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    self.inpItem.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Enter purchased item"))
    self.txtQty = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Qty: ")
    self.inpQty = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    self.txtPrice = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Price per Item $: ")
    self.inpPrice = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    self.inpPrice.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Do not add the $ sign"))
```

And the button code is as follows:

```
    self.addButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="Add Items")
    self.addButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddLine)
    self.addButton.ToolTip = wx.ToolTip("Update Database")
```

I've tried two different versions of ToolTips between the TextCtrl and the buttons just to see if it made any difference - it doesn't.

Running Python 3.6 on Mac OS Mojave, and wxPython tools.

Answer (score 0):

`self.addButton.ToolTip = wx.ToolTip("Update Database")` is creating a ToolTip object so it should work.

Try `self.addButton.ToolTip("Update Database")` instead.

If it is still giving you grief, add `wx.ToolTip.Enable(True)` (although on a Mac this may not be supported)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately, it didn't work. Compiled and ran fine, just again, no ToolTip displayed.

Comment: Just a thought! Do you get tooltips in other programs? If not it could be a system thing or timer setting as, in the tooltip shows so quickly that you don't see it.  If so see `wx.ToolTip.SetAutoPop(2000)` (show tip for 2 seconds)

Comment: i thought that myself after posting so I opened a few programs on my Mac and I do see tool tips, even with Eclipse, the software I am using to write my code with, and it also displays tool tips so will try your timer idea. I know that software in Python does differ between Mac and Windows. I have one program that displays a 'console' type window in a multi edit display. It never updates the messages on my Mac but works perfectly in Windows. Drives me nuts trying to code for cross platform when the same code doesn't work as expected in both Mac and Windows, obvious styling issues aside.

Comment: More confusion. I am running a Frame with two tabbed panels, both constructed identically. Tool tip works on the first panel, but not the second. Now I'm really confused......